# Remember Me function is not working on mobile devices

Tags: php, mobile, browser, authentication

I've made a remember me function for the login of my PHP Website.

I set a Cookie with a hash which I also store in the database. On the index.php I read the Cookie value and check if is it in the database.

It works without problems on any PC on any browser.

BUT: On a mobile device (smartphone & tablet) it does simply not work. I tested different mobile browsers. There is no settings like "delete Cookies on exit" or so and I accept on any browser even third party Cookies.

Can anybody help me? Thank you!
Chris

EDIT:
Here is my Code.
First: setting the Cookie when the "remember me" checkbox is checked.
Second: Check if Cookie is set and token is in DB.

```
// Set Cookie?
if (isset($checkme) && $checkme == 1) {

    // generate Token:
    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(30));
    // hash toke for DB
    $tokenDB = hash('sha384', $token);

    // set Cookie for 18 days
    setcookie('myCookieName', $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 18, "/", "sub.mydomain.ch", 1, 1);

    // write hasehd Token in DB.
    $res = db_abfrage( 'INSERT INTO tokens (users_fk, token) VALUES ('.$userid.', "'.$tokenDB.'")' );

}


// Check Cookie
if (isset($_COOKIE['myCookieName']) && $_COOKIE['myCookieName'] != "") {

    $tokenHash = filter_var($_COOKIE['myCookieName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $res = db_abfrage( 'SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE token = "' . hash('sha384', $tokenHash) . '" LIMIT 1' );
    $logininfos = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $res );

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1 ) {

        // Valid Token in Database...log user in!

    }

}
```

Comment: Give code, please

Comment: I just entered my code.

Comment: You set secure cookie (sixth parameter of `setcookie`). Maybe on mobile you use http instead https?

Comment: No, I have a .htacces file which direct always on the https page.

Comment: I now think, that for example the mobile Firefox deletes the coockie when I close the app. I've set that he should not do this, but I think acctually this is the problem... Has anybody experiences with that?